# why the kubernetes service ip could not expose backend port but the host ip

Tags: kubernetes

when scanned kubernetes v1.16.0 service cluster ip, it is not shown the service backend service expose port but the host expose port:

```
bash-4.4# nmap -T4 10.108.94.72
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-06-06 18:54 CST
Nmap scan report for service-mysql-for-portal-server.sre.svc.cluster.local (10.108.94.72)
Host is up (0.000011s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
8000/tcp open  http-alt
8443/tcp open  https-alt
9000/tcp open  cslistener
```

this is my service define:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: service-mysql-for-portal-server
  namespace: sre
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/sre/services/service-mysql-for-portal-server
  uid: a0f5e0e6-34ba-4e56-b147-bc48badcefc8
  resourceVersion: '113416'
  creationTimestamp: '2020-06-06T04:51:42Z'
  labels:
    app: service-mysql-for-portal-server
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"service-mysql-for-portal-server"},"name":"service-mysql-for-portal-server","namespace":"sre"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":3306,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":3306}],"sessionAffinity":"None","type":"ClusterIP"}}
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: apollo-mysql
  clusterIP: 10.108.94.72
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

why would this happen? what should I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you paste results from curl 10.108.94.72:3306 and execution kubectl get svc -o wide command ?

Comment: I remove the cluster ip of this service and set to `None`, and it works.@MaggieO

Comment: Can you paste this solution in post below your question ?